# US B1/B2 visa information

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I want to know if ITR(Income Tax Returns) is mandatory for B1/B2 visa or Form 16 is sufficient.
I have ITR for the current assessment year.

Will my visa be denied?
My company is sending me for a training purpose for one month.

Comment: Why don't you submit your ITR if you have it? (as mentioned in the question)

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

ITR is the supporting document that you can provide as an evidence to demonstrate the ability to support your trip. However, ITR, like any other supporting document, *is not mandatory* and is only used to convince the officer that the applicant has a valid Business reason to travel to the USA. You can always tell him that you have not submitted the ITR for this year and you can show the returns from previous years along with the letter from your employer, payslips and the bank statements.

```
Will my visa be denied? My company is sending me for a training purpose for one month.
```

Noone can answer this question. During the interview, you will have to convince the VO that you have enough ties to your home country and you don't intend to stay in the US after your training is over.